# Unable to update uitableview rows

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview, uialertview

I am trying to update selected rows of `UITableView` from `UIAlertView` inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. But I am facing a problem. Each time I try to update any row, it's only updates the first row irrespective of selection of row.
My code is:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

NSString *selectedrow = nil;

if (searching) {
    slCell=indexPath.row;
    selectedrow = [copyListOfItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter the Number of Quantity" message:@""
                                               delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

[alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Number of Item"];  
textfieldQty = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
textfieldQty.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
textfieldQty.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
textfieldQty.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
[alert show];
[alert release];
}
else {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter the Number of Quantity" message:@""
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Number of Item"];  
    textfieldQty = [alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textfieldQty.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textfieldQty.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textfieldQty.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [alert show];
    [alert release];
        }
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
NSString *b=nil;
if (buttonIndex == 0) {
    if (searching) {
        if([textfieldQty.text isEqualToString:b]) {
            UIAlertView *alert2 = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter plz" message:@""
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"OK"];
            [alert2 show];
            [alert2 release];
        }


    NSString *newqty = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",textfieldQty.text];
    DMSAppDelegate *d= (DMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    [d->tableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:slCell withObject:(id)newqty];

    NSLog(@"tb%@",copyListOfQty);

    }
    else {

        NSString *newqty = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",textfieldQty.text];
        DMSAppDelegate *d= (DMSAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        [d->tableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:slCell withObject:(id)newqty];
        [self.tablevieww reloadData];
    }

}   
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow below steps to achieve what you want.

1. While creating `UIAlertview` in `(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method, set alerview's tag as indexpath's row.
2. In delegate method  `-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex`, you try to access alertView's tag and pass that tag to the method call `[d->tableDataQt replaceObjectAtIndex:[alertView tag] withObject:(id)newqty];`
3. In AppDelegate class, you create one more method called `-(void)replaceObjectAtIndex:(NSInteger>inIndex withObject:(id)inObject`
4. In above newly created method try to access `UITableViewCell` from `UITableView` object with method call `UITableViewCell *myCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inIndex inSection:0];`
5. This way, you will get the object of `UITableViewCell` and alter the value of that and reload the table.

I hope this will help you. Please do not forget to put right mark if this resolves your problem. :)

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply lemme try  your method :)
Thanks again

Comment: you mentioned "set alertview's tag as indexpath'row". can you please explain it.
I didn't get it actually. you mean instance ?

Comment: `UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Enter the Number of Quantity" message:@""
                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert addTextFieldWithValue:@"" label:@"Number of Item"];  
    textfieldQty =[alert textFieldAtIndex:0];
    textfieldQty.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad;
    textfieldQty.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearanceAlert;
    textfieldQty.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    [alert show];[alert setTag: indexPath.row];
    [alert release];`